# Identifying a Project in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, project, atl, identity

I have a project that is coded in C. I can build it, change it. I can do whatever I want with it.

Now, the problem is, I have to identify it somehow. I looked to the Project Properties part, but couldn't find anything useful.

The real problem is that, the people I work for wants an ATL project that has some radio buttons and stuff. I'll work with EWF. But, my project has to be in the same type with their past programs. So, I can't create a window with Qt and give them. It has to meet with the requirements that they gave me. So, the sample project is coded under C and has ATL classes. There's a resource editor - which I found really useful.

When I delete some components from my project (using Resource Editor), there happens some execution time errors/exceptions. Code is trying to update some components, and can't find them.

So, is there a way of identifying the project? So that I can create the same type of project and use resource editor to add my buttons and stuff?

(It would be so easy if there's some sort of helper component for Visual Studio like the one in Eclipse. That I can select a variable and see it everywhere in code - where it used, changed, assigned...)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the vcproj file of your project, it should have properties like:

ProjectType=

Version=

ProjectGUID=

Keyword=

the above should be good to identify your project.
In case they are not, please explain why so that we find a solution.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know it's so easy. Take care.